# Create multiple columns based on the content of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

In a dataset i have a column containing letters, as follows:

```
d = data.frame(col1 = c("ABC", "CDE","ACE","BDF"))
d

  col1
1  ABC
2  CDE
3  ACE
4  BDF
```

I would like to create a column for each different letter that is contained in col1 and those column would be TRUE/FALSE, as follows:

```
  col1     A
1  ABC  TRUE
2  CDE FALSE
3  ACE  TRUE
4  BDF FALSE
```

But the thing is that i have 25 different ones. So to identify each different characters that is contained in the column i already have the function needed :

```
find.characters <- function(v1){
  x1 <- unique(unlist(strsplit(v1, '')))
  indx <- grepl('[A-Z]', x1)
  c(sort(x1[indx]), sort(x1[!indx]))
}
find.characters(d$col1)

[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

But i struggle to create a list of columns based on this list of characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `LETTERS` built-in character vector to create the column names and apply `grepl` on each of its elements:

```r
d[LETTERS] <- sapply(LETTERS, \(l) grepl(l, d$col1))
```

output

```r
#   col1     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J     K     L     M     N     O     P     Q     R
# 1  ABC  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2  CDE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3  ACE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4  BDF FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#       S     T     U     V     W     X     Y     Z
# 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I didnt know about the LETTERS built-in vector, thank you it works really well!

Answer (score 3):

There is a great library for operations such as this. It is called `splitstackshape` and you can use it in your case as:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(d, "col1", "", mode = "binary", type = "character", fill = 0)

  col1 col1_A col1_B col1_C col1_D col1_E col1_F
1  ABC      1      1      1      0      0      0
2  CDE      0      0      1      1      1      0
3  ACE      1      0      1      0      1      0
4  BDF      0      1      0      1      0      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try

```
> with(d, cbind(d, table(rev(stack(setNames(strsplit(col1, ""), seq_along(col1))))) > 0))
  col1     A     B     C     D     E     F
1  ABC  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  CDE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3  ACE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
4  BDF FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you your solution work aswell, + it also works with any characters contained in the col1 (numbers, special characters..)!